# How to remove views first title

Tags: views

I have a list of titles in a view block. But I never want the very first title of the view to display is this possible? I am using Drupal 7 with views 3.X

Answer (score 3):

In the pager settings of your view select the wanted amount of items and then specify an offset by 1, so the first item won't be displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Pager" settings for that. Set it to the kind of pager you want and use the "offset" to skip the first items.